# My websit dosent worke http errors 500

Tags: errors, https, localhost, 500-internal-error, static-website

Warning: Use of undefined constant DIR - assumed 'DIR' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/ki279095/public_html/index.php on line 4

Warning: require(DIR/wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ki279095/public_html/index.php on line 4

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'DIR/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/ki279095/public_html/index.php on line 4

Comment: You may be using `DIR` instead of `__DIR__` in `require()` command.